# Squid log to socket

Tags: tcp, squid

I've got a simple script listening on port 10101 (tcp) on my primary server which is meant to consume the log files of my proxy (which is running on a separate server).

Now, my problem is that I can't seem to get squid to log to tcp.

None of the following works*:

- access_log tcp://[ip]:10101 squid
- access_log /dev/tcp/[ip]/10101 squid

**Question:**

Why is this, and (more importantly) how *do* I make squid log to a socket?

*The first should work according to the documentation, there's no reason why the second shouldn't work.

Comment: The second doesn't work because `/dev/tcp` does not exist on Linux systems. It is specific to the *bash* shell.

Comment: Oh, well, that explains a lot (and at the same time it made me incredibly sad).

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

- Log to a socket is only supported in the legacy 2.7.x version. The function isn't ported to 3.1 yet.
- TCP is not supported. Only udp.

The syntax is:

```
access_log udp:x.x.x.x:port
```